# Work with empty activity android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello everybody I have this problem in **[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)**, when I create a new empty activity "onCreate" and "setContentView" and "R" becomes red, thanks for help me. My code-

[image]

Comment: Try clicking the first suggestion in the error message, "Install repository and sync project". Looks like you do not have the support library downloaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should click here-

[image]

This will automatically fix the issue if code is OK.

And if u just created it with Android Studio empty activity, then code will be OK always if your installation is OK.

So, if u just click on the given fix, that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle is not sync. This picture says your Android SDK is not contains "android.support.v7". There is 2 solutions.

one: Click on the error of page bottom "Install Repos..." and wait until download it and synced.

two: Change your class extends to "Activity" like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ....
}
```